# Show next ViewController in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have next simple code, for downloading info from service.

```
UIViewController *nextController;

[request authWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) 
{
    // Result of auth request
    if (!nextController) nextController = [UIViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController: nextController];
}];
```

And I need show next view when request return success.
I want to know - this code are correct, or I must create and show viewcontroller in another place, not in block?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you declare your viewcontroller outside your block? You only need him on completion

Comment: Well, I spot a missing opening bracket and a missing closing bracket.

Comment: Thomas, When I leave block ARC can delete all local variable. I think what controller saved in navigation controller, but I can create it in another blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code format is correct. But you can improve your code by below

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[request authWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) 
{
    // Result of auth request
    if (!error)
    {
        UIViewController *nextController = [UIViewController alloc] init];
        // pass result to nexview controller if you want..
        [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController: nextController];
    }

}
```